# Qemu device loader doesnt load value into memory

Tags: qemu

Im trying to use the -device,loader option in qemu. Originally, I wanted to load a file into memory, but that was (and still isnt) working. So, I tried to load a constant value into memory. This is my command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64              \
    -machine virt                \
    -cpu cortex-a57              \
    -smp 1                       \
    -m 3G                        \
    -device loader,addr=0x14680000,data=0xdeadbeef,data-len=0x4\
    -machine gic-version=3       \
    -machine secure=true         \
    -machine virtualization=true \
    -nographic                   \
    -S -s
```

I then open gdb, and do:

```
target remote :1234
x/x 0x14680000
```

The result is not 0xdeadbeef, as I had expected, but 0xffffffff.
Why is this happening? I cant find much documentation on the loader device in qemu, and have mostly just been following:
https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/generic-loader.html

Comment: it works when I try that for x86_64 version. There are no errors in any any part of the process?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean by errors in any part of the process. At the very least, qemu doesnt complain about invalid settings? Because of the -S option, no code should be run before I connect with gdb, so any program I load shouldnt affect it.(execution-wise. Perhaps if they had their own data there it might).

Comment: I was thinking of `gdb` errors when connecting to target

Comment: When I tried loading a file, it just full of 0